# Cordova input file crash

Tags: file, cordova, plugins, input

I'm developing a new Cordova Project.
I'm trying to implement the file-transfer plugin.

For this, the first step is to get a FileChooser and gets the FileEntry of the file i have selected.

My problem is : When i try to implement an input file type, i have the dialog window that open and when i try to select a file and then 'OK', my application simply crash.
i'm not able to catch the ERROR code.

Tried on Android 4.3 with CLI command : cordova run android.

ps: No need to tell me to use cordova-file plugin, it's not the purpose. Also tried.

Thanks a lot /

Comment: are you using an html input type file or a cordova plugin? which cordova version are you using?

Comment: Hey.
I'm using cordova 5.x (latest version).

I found the problem. The input works on Android since 4.4.
So Lollipop and Kitkat are supporting the input file.

However, Android version like JellyBeans doesn't support it.
Since it still represent 30% of the android users, that could be a real issue for application running with cordova.

Comment: No, input file should work on cordova for that versions, it's broken on android 4.4-4.4.1-4.4.2. I'll try tomorrow with latest version of cordova on an android 4.3 device, but it worked with previous versions of cordova

Comment: Since february 2015, <input file> is supported on Lollipop.
https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/02/06/cordova-android-3.7.1.html

I tried <input file> with Android 4.4.2 device and it works well.
Tried with 4.3, and it's not working.
Maybe the only issue come from this android version.
I would be glad to know what result you will have during your tests tomorrow. ;)

Comment: And since december 2013 input file support was added to cordova (on version 2.4.0) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2086, and it worked on android 4.3, maybe it broke when lollipop support was added, as I said, I'll try tomorrow

Comment: Just tried on 4.1.1 and 4.3 devices and worked fine (cordova cli 5.2.0, cordova android 4.1.1), code <input type="file" name="pic">